# Accessing a PHP variable from a JavaScript function in a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, sql, html

Im sure this is possible, but I don't know JavaScript or PHP well enough to be able to figure it out myself!

I have an SQL database storing postcodes. I can retrieve that data from the database using PHP and get it showing in the webpage using:

`<?php echo $row_getPosts['postcode']; ?>`

However, I want to access this postcode in a JavaScript function in the head of the webpage. I've tried defining a `var` in the java and simply putting the code above into it, but that's mixing the PHP and the JavaScript languages together, an 'apples and pears' situation!!

Im presuming I must define a global variable i the html file, which both the PHP and JavaScript can interact with, but I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can jsut echo it inside the js function

Comment: Please don't mix JS and PHP like Dagon suggests. Works, sloppily, but debugging sucks. Embed a hidden input. <input id="myvalue" value="<?php echo $var ?>"> Then use JS to grab the element myvalue and get its value.

Comment: @Rottingham disagree, it has its place

Comment: @Dagon Sloppy does have a place in a lot of hearts.

Comment: @Rottingham define sloppy?

Comment: Mixing multiple languages in a single line of code. Slovenly, untidy. Here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sloppy?s=t

Comment: so its an opinion- well every one has one of those

Comment: More a matter of debugging @Dagon. If you screw something up mixing that into a JS line, you break the entire script thereafter. Separating the concerns a little actually does the programmer some favors. *shrug* It is an opinion yes.

Comment: Embed an input? No, that's sloppy. If you're going global with the vars and need to output them, it would be tidiest to put them before the rest of your JS loads, as a single `<script>var ...</script>` tag that contains all the necessary variables. Then use the variables in your JS. No mixing PHP with JS, or JS with unnecessary HTML form elements untidy dotted around.

Comment: setting javascript variables at runtime via php is done all the time. @ rottingham, why have the javascript overhead of finding the hidden input and needing all those extra lines of code? I am perfectly comfortable using php to set my variables, I even use php to echo variables into my body onload functions set per users needs. Works great for Joomla and wordpress and other CMS plugins

Comment: When did 'done all the time' become 'good to do'? People hurt people all the time too. I'll take the beat down here, standing for my opinion :-)

Comment: While I agree with @Rottingham in that for a more complicated webpage that keeping things separate is a good thing, as my webpage is pretty simply and im only using it as a learning tool to see how the different languages interact, ive accepted pathfinders answer. Thanks for all the info though - im getting there slowly!

Comment: I would always use json_encode though when passing a variable from php to JavaScript. It is good practice as it ensures a valid format.

Comment: Ive heard of json, but never looked into its meaning, use or practises as of yet, and as im very new to this, i think its wise for me to stick to the basics, for the time being at least... unless you think its an integral part of learning javascript??

Comment: json_encode is great for passing objects and I would highly recommend learning how it works both from php and how it interacts with javascript, but for passing a simple string, simple is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are echoing can be echoed inside a variable in the head of the same file or inside the function you are writing to the head:

```
<script>
var postcode = '<?php echo $row_getPosts['postcode']; ?>';
</script>
```

be sure this variable is put before the function runs in the head though.

or if the function is available, you could put it there too:

```
function blah() {
var postcode = '<?php echo $row_getPosts['postcode']; ?>';
rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
var variable = <?php echo json_encode($row_getPosts['postcode']); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
<?php
$postcode= $row_getPosts['postcode'];
echo '
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  var postcode = "'.$postcode.'";
 </script>
';
?>
```

Comment: would you make yourself a page and try this??

Comment: You just copied what someone else has since put. Can you tell us what was wrong with your original code..?

Comment: Nothing really, it's besically the same thing.

Comment: No they weren't not the same. What you posted would not have worked.

Comment: @Popnoodles: I have updated my code to show what I meant to show originally.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't do this at some appropriate point in your code.

```
<?php
    $postcode = "SomePostCode";
    echo '<script> var postCode = "'.$postcode.'";</script>';
?>
```

This will create a global variable. You can just inject the variable into a function if it's more appropriate, in which case you won't need the `<script>` tags.